# Normalizing Depth Coverage among samples

Tags: r, normalization, sapply, bioconductor

This is an open question that aims to define states for each position in the genome (correspondent to a "CpG" sites) that vary among samples. 
The reason for this question is that the tools available, define status of a CpG windows and not for individual CpGs.

I have a table like this:
The columns are: Chromosome number (chr), initial (start) and final (end) position of a interest base, the expected coverage (depth), the observed coverage to different 6 animals (depth1-depth6).

```
data <- "chr start end depth depth1 depth2 depth3 depth4 depth5 depth6
chr1 3273 3273 7 200 35 1 200 850 0
chr1 3274 3274 3 50 25 5 300 1500 2
chr1 3275 3275 8 600 15 8 100 300 5
chr1 3276 3276 4 30 2 10 59 20 0
chr1 3277 3277 25 20 7 4 600 45 0"
data <- read.table(text=data, header=T)
```

I need to define a column with the states of each line, the states are: not covered region, alternately covered and often covered.

To do that, first, I need to do a normalization of the depth among samples to obtain values that can be compared between the individuals.
and, second, I have to define the range between the states (By now, any range is acceptable);

I found this script that does something similar to what I need to normalize the depths, but I could not apply to my case yet (this script was designed to "CpG windows" and displays frequency of "C" and "G" in each window.

```
setMethod("normalizeCoverage", "methylRawList",

                        function(obj,method){

                          if(method=="median"){
                            x=sapply(obj,function(x) median(x$coverage) )
                          }else if(method=="mean"){
                            x=sapply(obj,function(x) mean(x$coverage) )
                          }else{
                            stop("method option should be either 'mean' or 'median'\n")
                          }
                          sc.fac=max(x)/x #get scaling factor
                          for(i in 1:length(obj)){
                            all.cov=obj[[i]]$coverage
                            fCs    =obj[[i]]$numCs/all.cov
                            fTs    =obj[[i]]$numT/all.cov
                            obj[[i]]$coverage=round(sc.fac[i]*obj[[i]]$coverage)
                            obj[[i]]$numCs   =round(obj[[i]]$coverage*fCs)
                            obj[[i]]$numTs   =round(obj[[i]]$coverage*fTs)
                          }
                          obj

    })
```

I have checked also this "edge package"function for R, which is used for RNAseq standardization data, that looks like this:

```
calcNormFactors(object, method=c("TMM","RLE","upperquartile","none"), refColumn = NULL,
      logratioTrim = .3, sumTrim = 0.05, doWeighting=TRUE, Acutoff=-1e10, p=0.75)
```

but also I could not apply to my data yet.

What I hope for my final result is something like this:

```
chr start State
chr1 3273 Often
chr1 3274 alternatively
chr1 3275 no
chr1 3276 often
chr1 3277 no
```

but I would be really satisfied only with the normalized depth to each sample coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the first part of the problem (normalization)

"Compute depth-adjusted coverage values, a straight-up application of the cpm function to the count matrix might be sufficient. This will convert your counts into count-per-million values that you can then compare informally between samples". 
(Aaron Lun,Cambridge, United Kingdom)

Normalize by "cpm" by "edgeR" package from R

```
datamatrix <- data [, c(4:10)]
library (edgeR)

#grouping factor
group <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) #groups of each sample)

#create a DGEList
y <- DGEList(counts=datamatrix,group=group)

#########
$counts
  depth depth1 depth2 depth3 depth4 depth5 depth6
1     7    200     35      1    200    850      0
2     3     50     25      5    300   1500      2
3     8    600     15      8    100    300      5
4     4     30      2     10     59     20      0
5    25     20      7      4    600     45      0

$samples
       group lib.size norm.factors
depth      1       47            1
depth1     2      900            1
depth2     2       84            1
depth3     2       28            1
depth4     2     1259            1
depth5     2     2715            1
depth6     2        7            1
##################
#normalize
y <- calcNormFactors(y)

########
> y
An object of class "DGEList"
$counts
  depth depth1 depth2 depth3 depth4 depth5 depth6
1     7    200     35      1    200    850      0
2     3     50     25      5    300   1500      2
3     8    600     15      8    100    300      5
4     4     30      2     10     59     20      0
5    25     20      7      4    600     45      0

$samples
       group lib.size norm.factors
depth      1       47    0.7423735
depth1     2      900    0.5526927
depth2     2       84    0.9534847
depth3     2       28    0.8652676
depth4     2     1259    0.6588115
depth5     2     2715    1.0358307
depth6     2        7    4.3289213
##########################################

> cpm(y)
      depth     depth1    depth2    depth3    depth4     depth5    depth6
1 200621.61  402071.90 436993.56  41275.42 241125.49 302245.841      0.00
2  85980.69  100517.97 312138.26 206377.10 361688.24 533375.014  66001.27
3 229281.84 1206215.69 187282.96 330203.36 120562.75 106675.003 165003.16
4 114640.92   60310.78  24971.06 412754.21  71132.02   7111.667      0.00
5 716505.76   40207.19  87398.71 165101.68 723376.48  16001.250      0.00
```

Normalized!

Even with normalization, I have 3 samples that have a lot of values equal to zero, since they have low coverage. I think I'll have to delete them from analysis.
I thought about making a PCA test to see how these samples are grouped.

I would like some feedback on the method used for normalization
and for the second part of my problem